# How to pass a function with arguments as prop in React without creating an arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function

```js
doSomething = (id) => {
  console.log(id) 
}
```

I want to call this function inside onPress. I know one way to do this is by using another arrow function inside onPress like this:

```js
<Text onPress={() => this.doSomething(id)}>Do Some Work</Text>
```

But then a new function is created in every re-render and decreases peformance which can be avoided by calling functions like this `onPress={this.doSomething}` only when there is no argument to be passed. Is a similar thing possible with arguments so that I can improve the performance of my app

Comment: It is not possible to do something similar with an argument. But unless you have like 10000 of them at each re-render, I don't think the performance difference would be perceived...

Comment: i don't think so, since the function is called with the event object as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely right, arrow function creates a new function every time, that's why React's shallow equal props comparison returns `false`.

You could use `useCallback` hook to create a momoized callback.
So, I believe you have the `id` variable in your `render` function.

```js
const doSomething = useCallback((e) => {
  console.log(id)
}, [id])


<Text onPress={doSomething} />
```

Memoized `doSomething` function will be changed every time when the `id` variable is changed.

However, by default if the parent component updates then every child will be updated as well. Unless it has `memo` wrapper, or `shouldComponentUpdate` life-cycle hook defined.

You can read a bit more about memoization in context of React components in a great [article](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/#memoization) written by Dan Abramov.

**UPD**

If you are using a class component then you could return a momized function from the class method.

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
 
  // I used Lodash memoize for example

  doSomething = _.memoize((id) => {
    return function (e) {
      console.log(id)
    }
  })

  render () {
    return (
      <Text onPress={doSomething(id)} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using a class component not a function component. This  id  variable is only available in render() scope so it means this function also should be in same scope ?

Comment: Updated my answer. The main idea to use memoized wrapper around your function. It could be anything: `_.memoize` or even custom implementation (it's really simple). Don't forget to use `PureComponent` for your `<Text />` or to define custom logic in `shouldComponentUpdate`